# Can not connect between android device and node.js server

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, socket.io

So here, I'm trying to connect my android to my server node.js, using the socket.io but during the execution, there is no error but the connection has not been established and returns me false

Thank you in advance for your help !

Socket.Java

```
package com.example.myprojectapplication.ObjectClass;

import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Socket {

    private com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("localhost:8081/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Relevant part of my MainActivity

```
com.example.myprojectapplication.ObjectClass.Socket app = new com.example.myprojectapplication.ObjectClass.Socket();
Socket mSocket = app.getSocket();
mSocket.connect();
```

Node.js Server

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('message', 'Android Connected');
  console.log("Android Connected");

  socket.on('message', function(message){
    console.log("message received");
    socket.emit('message', 'message received');
  });

});

server.listen(8081)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Socket.Java your using `localhost:8081/` Instead of this address you have to use node.js server IP address (Local IP address). To connect your application with node.js server you have to keep your computer and application running device in same network.

Comment: Even if everything is simulated locally?

Comment: yes, because for android simulator localhost means own address and you want to point server which is running on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct. But one other thing to note : if you are using an emulator, then you can use 10.0.2.2 to refer to the localhost of the host computer. This is very useful for development because you won't have to get the actual IP addresses of your laptop each time you change the network.

See :https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking for more info

Comment: Thanks man... this really worked for me. I was using my IP address the whole time instead of 10.0.2.2